# Metadata in status index is not updating

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

I have the following sample sitemap with URl's and meta data. I'm able to crawl the sitemap and its metadata  successfully. But when I update the metadata in sitemap.xml for the URl's, meta data is not updating on next fetch date.

**Sample Sitemap.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:news="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>/index.html</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-12-30T14:47:00.0000Z</lastmod>
        <title>Home</title>
        <originalName>home</originalName>
        <effectiveDate></effectiveDate>
        <externalAccess></externalAccess>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>/PDF_1000195118.pdf</loc>
        <lastmod>2021-01-04T14:49:00.0000Z</lastmod>
        <title>The power</title>
        <description>test document </description>
        <originalName>PDF_1000195118.pdf</originalName>
        <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>        
        <externalAccess>false</externalAccess>
        <excludeFromSearch>true</excludeFromSearch>     
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Status index:

```
 {
        "_index" : "status",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "16276148886a4de6cb055be68f45580043bf855269b2b784ef47e830fbf6f942",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {         
          "status" : "FETCHED",
          "metadata" : {
            "excludeFromSearch" : [
              "true"
            ],
            "lastModifiedDate" : [
              "2021-01-04 20:19:00"
            ],
            "loggedInOnly" : [
              "false"
            ],
            "description" : [
              "test document "
            ],
            "mimeType" : [
              "application/pdf"
            ],
            "title" : [
              "The power"
            ],
            "externalAccess" : [
              "false"
            ],
            "depth" : [
              "1"
            ],
            "isSitemap" : [
              "false"
            ],
            "fetch%2Eerror%2Ecount" : [
              "1"
            ],
          
          "nextFetchDate" : "2021-01-04T12:13:04.000Z"
        }
```

After that I changed **excludeFromSearch** in sitemap.xml  to **false** . But it didn't get updated.

How can I update the metadata after successful fetch?

Answer (score 0):

That's because *DISCOVERED* URLs are created in ES only if they don't exist.

The initial discovery created an entry in the *status* index with the status *DISCOVERED*, when you changed the sitemap, it sent the modified DISCOVERED document to ES but it got ignored because there already was a document with that URL there.

One way around it would be to delete the documents in the *status* index prior to updating your sitemap **or** updating the document directly.

Sitemaps in StormCrawler are used for discovery only, docs in *status* are never updated, just overridden when the URLs are processed.

Comment: Thank you @julien-nioche for the quick reply. Is there any way to update documents metadata through crawler once the URL crawled successfully?

Comment: not from the sitemaps for the reasons I explained above. The document will get overridden with one with the status FETCHED but it will have not the metadata from the latest sitemap.